# How can I make Mac OS X Address Book display a person’s home address from an LDAP server?

Tags: macos, address-book, ldap

(I've posted this question on Stack Overflow first, but someone told me it belonged here.)

I have a custom LDAP server, which I can customize to generate whichever object class and attributes I need. I'm trying to display people from that server in the Mac OS X address book.

Names and organizations display correctly, as well as work-related phone and address. However, I've never been able to have a home address displayed in the address book.

This is an example of output from running a ldapsearch:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (givenName=Joh*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# 10041, example.com
dn: uid=10041,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: mozillaOrgPerson
uid: 10041
cn: John Doe
givenName: John
sn: Doe
o: Acme
telephoneNumber: 500 00 00
mobile: 500 00 00
mail: john.doe@example.com
street: Baker St
postalCode: 10098
l: New York
c: US
homePostalAddress: White St
mozillaHomePostalCode: 10098
mozillaHomeLocalityName: New York
mozillaHomeCountryName: US

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Every piece of information shows up in the address book up to here:

```
homePostalAddress: White St
mozillaHomePostalCode: 10098
mozillaHomeLocalityName: New York
mozillaHomeCountryName: US
```

Which object class or attribute name should I use to have the home address show up in the Mac OS X address book?

Comment: Check the Schema: abxldap.schema

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup mappings on the OS X machine. It's under the LDAP stuff under directory services. There you will find mappings that map what OS X wants to what you have in LDAP.